# Any older Browser version which supports SVG, but not canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas, raphael

The latest version of browsers (like Chrome) by default support Canvas, and not SVG. Hence, in this code in js -

```
    if (Modernizr.canvas) {
        require(['jCanvas'], _.bind(_callCanvasMethod, this));
    }
    else {
        require(['raphael'], _.bind(_callSVGRenderingMethod, this));
    }
```

By default, Modernizr.canvas is true, hence the code always enters first block (Canvas) and not the second block (to use Raphael, SVG).

I'm trying to **find an older browser version of either IE or chrome for both MAC and Windows** that doesn't use canvas and uses SVG and test the second block (_callSVGRenderingMethod method).

Comment: maybe IE8 per https://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: @JonSG - Microsoft's now discontinued browser for Mac. https://internet-explorer-for-mac.en.softonic.com/mac

Comment: @JonSG - From your link, I tried installing an older version of Safari (Version 10), but I'm not able to replace the existing version. 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286080/how-to-install-a-specific-version-build-of-safari
My current Safari version is Version 11.1.1 (13605.2.8)

Comment: On that page click the "show all" button.  If you want to test with Safari that does not support canvass it looks like you need to go back to version 3, maybe even farther.  I don't know how you would do that on Mac, but Microsoft does offer virtual machines with IE 8 to test with.  see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Comment: @JonSG - You mentioned, "version 3" for Safari. Why so, when the link says Safari got Canvas support after version 10. Can't we get version 10?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure where you are getting the Version 10 info.  On the caniuse page with the show all selected I see partial support starting a v 3.1 for safari and on the mdn page for canvass i see basic support starting a v2  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas  I think an IE8 vm is your best testing platform

Comment: That helped! Thanks a lot.